# remove UISwitch thumb shadow effect - swift

Tags: swift, uiswitch

I'm trying to remove shadow effect exists on UISwitch. Is there any way to remove this shadow effect?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean remove the shadow ?

Comment: That shadow effect you see in the picture, on the left side of thumb @ShauketSheikh

Comment: no, not that line. there's a shadow effect below thumb @UmaMadhavi

Answer (score 0):

It seems using thumbTintColor removes shadow effect

Answer (score -1):

**For Swift 3/4:**

Use

```
yourSwitch.thumbTintColor = .clear
```

**For Objective-C**

```
yourswitch setThumbTintColor: [UIColor clearColor];
```

Hope that works for you.

Comment: this removes my uiswitch button. Why so?